# Why is the table attribute of Hashtable serialized?

Tags: java, hashtable, transient

Why is the `table` field of `Hashtable` serialized, although it is marked as `transient`?

Comment: A code sample and possibly Java version would help in answering your question.

Comment: @msw - not really.  Anyone who is experienced with Java knows where to find the source code for Hashtable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is marked as transient because it is unsafe to use the default serialization scheme on the Entry array.  Rather, when a Hashtable is deserialized, the keys in the table must be rehashed and the entries must be added to slots according to the new hashcode values.  This is necessary because the keys may have different hashcodes after deserialization ... for a variety of reasons.  This work will be done by Hashtable's `readObject()` method.

Comment: More generally it cuts the dependency between implementation and serialisation format, so that the former can change whilst the latter stays compatible. You can see ugly hacks where serialisation wasn't thought about.

Answer (score 1):

Because it has `writeObject()` and `readObject()` implemented (in private methods), with which it can control how it is to be serialized and deserialized. It's around line 800 in Java 1.6 source code.

Check this [Sun advanced serialization guide](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/) for details how it works "under the hoods".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me also why it is declared transient.

Comment: So that it does not "automatically" get serialized which would cause data duplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of the Hashtable class (at least in 1.6), the `Entry[] table` is marked as `transient` but the class implements `writeObject()`, in which it writes the contents of the entry table to the `ObjectOutputStream`.

Thus the contents of the Hashtable are always serialized.

Why did they choose to implement it this way? Likely to have control over how the array is serialized.