# HashMap and issue with Serializable

Tags: java, serialization

when i try to call function which return :  `List<Map.Entry<Integer, List<Object>>>` I get this error :

> java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.HashMap$Node

Note : All class **implements Serializable**

Comment: `HashMap` class is serialized by default which means we need not to implement `Serializable` interface.

Comment: The `HashMap.Node` class is the implementation of the `Map.Entry` interface, used by `HashMap`. It is NOT `Serializable`.

Comment: You aren't gettiing this just by calling a function. Somewhere you are doing Serialization and deserialization.

Comment: @EJP Can you please explain more ??

Comment: No, I don't think I can. I expressed myself clearly. What part of 'somewhere you are doing Serialization and deserialization' don't you understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HasMap` itself is serializable but `Map.Entry` isn't. You need to use some other type.

For curious [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524140/why-is-the-table-attribute-of-hashtable-serialized) is explanation why,

Comment: So in order to keep my class serializable, can i replace Map.Entry by HashMap ??